# Difference between == and === in JS

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators, equality-operator, identity-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

What's the difference between `==` and `===`? Also between `!==` and `!==`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are lots of answers to this question on Stackoverflow already.

Short:

`==` only compares values

`===` compares values + type

---

```
var check1 = '10',
    check2 = 10;

check1 == check2 // true
check1 === check2 // false
```

Answer (score 1):

"==" means equals, whereas "===" means identically equal.

In short, "==" will try and coerce/convert the types of values when doing a comparison, so "2"==2, whereas "===" will not.