# If then else using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been playing around with the script and can't get it working. It always defaults to option3.

Can anyone help?

```
<select id="select">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>

document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("select").value = "option1") {
    option = "option 1 chosen";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("select").value = "option2") {
    option = "option 2 chosen";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("select").value = "option3") {
    option = "option 3 chosen";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = option;
}

</script>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

Comment: In all your if queries is the sigle equals sign wrong. It must be `==`instead of `=`

Comment: The condition has assignment statement not comparison statement. Kindly learn correctly.

Comment: In your if statement, == to compare value, not =.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a dupe of the question is was closed in favor of.

Comment: @j08691 I agree with you... Until you find a dupe, let it be closed for the enormous number of answers that say the contents of the above comment.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah T.J. found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`=` assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) is used to assign values to a variable to the left of the sign. The [`==` abstract equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) or [`===` strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) is used to compare values.

```
function myFunction() {
  if(document.getElementById('select').value === 'option1') {
    option = 'option 1 choosen';
  }
  if(document.getElementById('select').value === 'option2') {
    option = 'option 2 choosen';
  }
  if(document.getElementById('select').value === 'option3') {
    option = 'option 3 choosen';
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = option;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `==`, not `===`.

Comment: no, "==" is truthy, in all professional code I have done "===" is the preferred method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323377/difference-between-and-in-js

Comment: No. `==` is standard for comparing values. `===` is standard for comparing the value AND the type. In this instance, he's comparing values. **For example** Given that `x = 5`, `x == "5"` is true. `x === "5"` is false.

Comment: all well and good. In the company I work for, "==" would fail code review. It might be technically correct....but it practice...it isn't.

Comment: @E.Maggini don't be bullied into accepting edits that conflict with your intent. You're absolutely right.